# How to install s3 in aws cdk using Jenkins?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jenkins, pip, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on AWS cdk to create s3 bucket. I am using my enterprise jenkins to create pipeline. Below is my python code for creating s3 bucket.

*app.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from aws_cdk import core

from basic_stack import MyStack

app = core.App()
MyStack(app, "hello-cdk-1", env={'region': 'ap-southeast-2'})

app.synth()
```

Below us my *basic_stack.sh*

```
import os
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_s3 as s3,
    core
)

class MyStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        environment = os.environ['ENVIRONMENT']
        bucket_id = 'MyBucketId'
        bucket_name = 'my-bucket-name'
        public_access = s3.BlockPublicAccess(
            block_public_acls = True,
            block_public_policy = True,
            ignore_public_acls = True,
            restrict_public_buckets=True)
        s3.Bucket(self, bucket_id,
            bucket_name = f'kmartau-{bucket_name}-{environment}',
            block_public_access = public_access,
            encryption = s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED)
```

Below is my jenkins pipeline.

```
 withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: "${env.PROJECT_ID}-aws-${env.ENVIRONMENT}"]]) {
            docker.image("${ECR_HOST}/sharedtools/cdk:latest").inside {
              sh "./scripts/build.sh"
            }
```

Below is *build.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

# http://blog.kablamo.org/2015/11/08/bash-tricks-eux/
set -euxo pipefail
cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."

cd aws
python3 -m venv .env && \
  source .env/bin/activate && \
  pip install aws-cdk.cdk
  pip install aws-cdk.core
  cdk synth
```

So whenever I ru pipeline I get the below error.

```
The directory '/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting aws-cdk.s3
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aws-cdk.s3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for aws-cdk.s3
```

Can someone help me to figure it out the issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `aws-cdk.cdk` this module has been deprecated and renamed to `@aws-cdk/core` https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.cdk/. Also since you are using `python3` you should use `pip3`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just kept these two commands   pip install aws-cdk.core
  pip install aws-cdk.aws-s3. Now I started getting error CDK CLI >= 1.10.0 is required to interact with this app. May I know what may be the issue

Comment: you are facing error in `cdk synth`, right ? You need to upgrade your version.

Comment: Yeah how can i upgrade version?

Comment: `npm install -g aws-cdk: Why do you need Node.js when you're a Python, C#, or Java developer? The AWS CDK is developed in TypeScript and transpiled to JavaScript. Bindings for the other supported languages make use of the AWS CDK engine running on Node.js, as does the cdk command-line tool.`